# I still got ImmutableMultiDict([]) from request.files even if I add the name form my imput file

Tags: python, ajax, flask

I'm new in Flask and I try to upload images using ajax. I still got `ImmutableMultiDict([])` from `request.files` even if I add the name form my input file. I tried many solutions but no one worked for me.

**js-ajax **

```
$(document).ready(function () {
//alert('ya allah');

$('#upload-file').on('submit', function (event) {

    var formDataRaw = $('#upload-file')[0];
    var form_data = new FormData(formDataRaw);
    $.ajax({
        data: {
            normal: +'',
            anormal: +'',
            r: +'',
            form_data
        },
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/process',
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        processData: false,
        async: false
    })
        .done(function (data) {#....some code
        });

    event.preventDefault();

});

});
```

I add the name in the input file also.

**html side**

```
<form id="upload-file" method="POST" enctype=multipart/form-data>
                <fieldset style="border: none">
                    <div class="mt-2">

                        <label class="file btn btn-outline-gs m-2 my-sm-0 px-4 d_upload">
                            Upload IMG!
                            <input  type="file"
                                    id="imgInp"
                                    name="photo"
                                    class="i_upload"
                                    hidden/>
                        </label>

                    </div>
                </fieldset>

                <fieldset style="border: none">
                <div class="mb-2">
                        <input id="test"
                               type="submit"
                               value="Predect"
                               class="btn btn-outline-gs"
                               onclick="load(this)"/>
                    </div>
                </fieldset>

            </form>
```

and I think the code is clean but still got ImmutableMultiDict([]) from request.files, or just those brackets with `request.files['input name']`:

```
    if 'photo' in request.files:
        photo = request.files['photo']
        if photo.filename != '' and allowed_file(photo.filename):
            photo.save(os.path.join('static/uploads', photo.filename))
            print(photo.filename)
           f=secure_filename(photo.filename)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in my jQuery (ajax) code, **this one**:

```
data: {
            normal: +'',
            anormal: +'',
            r: +'',
            form_data
        },
```

I pass other attribute with form_data, and this is incorrect. **It should be just like this**:

```
data: form_data
```

and instead of this `data.name` it should be `data['name']`.